# CodeIgniter dynamic database in database.php

Tags: codeigniter

I want to change a variable in database.php to be dynamic. I want to create a field to get a value and then pass it into a variable in database.php instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could always modify the database.php file via http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php